# Solution for $a^x = b x^{-2}$

Tags: exponential-function, real-numbers, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I encountered an equation of the form $a^x = b x^{-2}$, where $a$, $b$ and $x$ are real numbers. But I am not sure if there is an analytical solution for this type of equations. I would appreciate it if you could point some directions as to where to look.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Put it in Wolfram and he'll give you the answer  with the Lambert fonction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a$, $b$ and $x$ are real numbers, rewriting your equation as
$$b=x^2a^x=(xe^{\frac{\ln{a}}{2}x})^2,$$
shows that there are no solutions if $b<0$. If $b>0$ then setting $w:=\tfrac{\ln{a}}{2}x$ yields
$$we^w=\pm\tfrac{\ln{a}}{2}\sqrt{b},$$
the solutions of which are given precisely by the Lambert $W$ function; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) for more information.

Comment: Have you seen Wolfram before your answer?

Comment: @Piquito No; is there something wrong?